# Enable button for a limited time period in a day in Adndroid

Tags: android, android-view, timed

I have a button it should work according to time from 09.00 Am to 04.00 pm and rest of time it should not work.

I am developing an app. I am new in android. I have three buttons namely register, events, gallery.

When I click register button it should work according to time mentioned above.
if the user click register on  that time it should pass on to the next activity and rest of times the button  click action should not work.

Comment: Use the Date and Calendar classes.

Comment: @Sali Suban Get current time and set condition on onclicklistner of button..

Comment: sir will you give some piece of code. so that i can pick up easily

Comment: i dont know how to use

Comment: When user click on resister button at that time get current date n time, convert date n time into timestamp. If timestamp is between 9 am to 4pm (also convert  date n time into timestamp) , then do your coding there.

Comment: Instead of asking code upfront why don't you try something and ask if you are stuck somewhere

Comment: i dont know how to put condition

Comment: thank you and i have achieved the goal. thanks for your ideas....

Answer (score -1):

check for class [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

on app start create AlarmManage class service with 
time gap current to desable/enable time in milisecond.

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final int PERIOD = 1200000;//20*60*1000; 20 minutes


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent i) {
        scheduleAlarms(ctxt);
    }

    public static void scheduleAlarms(Context ctxt) {
        AlarmManager mgr =
                (AlarmManager) ctxt.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(ctxt, AuthenticateService.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(ctxt, 0, i, 0);
        mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + PERIOD, PERIOD, pi);
    }
```